# Trying to calculate difference between 2 select queries in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Fairly new to SQL but I'm trying to get the difference between 2 select queries from the same Table. I have tried the following

```
SELECT
(SELECT KwhMeter,IndexElek,CalorieMeter,IndexWarmte,IndexWarmWater,IndexKoudWater,Date FROM Energiemeters WHERE Date = '2017-05-01')
 -
(SELECT KwhMeter,IndexElek,CalorieMeter,IndexWarmte,IndexWarmWater,IndexKoudWater,Date FROM Energiemeters WHERE Date = '2017-04-01') AS Difference
```

but I end up having the following error :

```
 #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Comment: Edit your question and define what you mean by "difference".  Sample data and desired results can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows that are on May 1st but not April 1st, then one way is to use aggregation:

```
SELECT KwhMeter, IndexElek, CalorieMeter, IndexWarmte, IndexWarmWater, IndexKoudWater, Date
FROM Energiemeters
WHERE Date IN ('2017-04-01', '2017-05-01')
GROUP BY KwhMeter, IndexElek, CalorieMeter, IndexWarmte, IndexWarmWater, IndexKoudWater
HAVING MIN(Date) = '2017-05-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Cross Join`. This is with the assumption that you get only 1 row per date.

```
Select 
(a.KwhMeter-b.KwhMeter) as KwhMeter,
(a.IndexElek-b.IndexElek) as IndexElek,
(a.CalorieMeter-b.CalorieMeter) CalorieMeter,
(a.IndexWarmte-b.IndexWarmte) IndexWarmte,
(a.IndexWarmWater-b.IndexWarmWater) IndexWarmWater,
(a.IndexKoudWater-b.IndexKoudWater) IndexKoudWater,
(a.Date-b.Date) as Date
from
(
SELECT distinct KwhMeter,IndexElek,CalorieMeter,IndexWarmte,IndexWarmWater,IndexKoudWater,Date 
FROM Energiemeters 
WHERE Date = '2017-05-01' 
) a
cross join
(
SELECT distinct KwhMeter,IndexElek,CalorieMeter,IndexWarmte,IndexWarmWater,IndexKoudWater,Date 
FROM Energiemeters 
WHERE Date = '2017-04-01' 
) b;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you want to subtract the respective values of columns from two rows determined by dates `2017-05-01` and `2017-04-01`?

If yes, then the query can be written as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE Date 
               WHEN '2017-05-01' THEN KwhMeter
               WHEN '2017-04-01' THEN -KwhMeter
           END) AS KwhMeter,
       SUM(CASE Date 
               WHEN '2017-05-01' THEN IndexElek
               WHEN '2017-04-01' THEN -IndexElek
           END) AS IndexElek, 
       SUM(CASE Date 
               WHEN '2017-05-01' THEN CalorieMeter
               WHEN '2017-04-01' THEN -CalorieMeter
           END) AS CalorieMeter,
       SUM(CASE Date 
               WHEN '2017-05-01' THEN IndexWarmte
               WHEN '2017-04-01' THEN -IndexWarmte
           END) AS IndexWarmte,
       SUM(CASE Date 
               WHEN '2017-05-01' THEN IndexWarmWater
               WHEN '2017-04-01' THEN -IndexWarmWater
           END) AS IndexWarmte, 
       SUM(CASE Date 
               WHEN '2017-05-01' THEN IndexKoudWater 
               WHEN '2017-04-01' THEN -IndexKoudWater 
           END) AS IndexKoudWater
FROM Energiemeters
WHERE Date IN ('2017-05-01', '2017-04-01')
```

A small scale working demo can be found [here](http://rextester.com/KQOU29585).

Comment: This works great thanks! But what if I have multiple columns with the same date. To add some context : The columns I am selecting also has an apartment number and I am using this to compare how much the value's have increased over time for each of my apartments (Thats why i am using a date)

Comment: Please can you add into the question some sample data of the setup you describe above and a depiction of the expected result out of it? Only working on guesses wouldn't really be a good idea to weave a solution around as yet unknown parameters.

Answer (score -1):

WORKING IN MOST RDBMSs EXCEPT MYSQL:

If I wanted to compute per-column difference I would use common table expressions to prepare subresults and then compute difference.

```
WITH 
res1 AS
(SELECT KwhMeter,IndexElek,CalorieMeter,IndexWarmte,IndexWarmWater,IndexKoudWater,Date FROM Energiemeters WHERE Date = '2017-05-01'),
res2 AS
(SELECT KwhMeter,IndexElek,CalorieMeter,IndexWarmte,IndexWarmWater,IndexKoudWater,Date FROM Energiemeters WHERE Date = '2017-04-01')
SELECT
r1.KwhMeter - r2.KwhMeter, r1.OtherColumnName - r2.OtherColumnName ... FROM res1 r1, res2 r2
```

However ... This works perfectly on 1 row per subselect (date). Do you guarentee one entry per date? Is that a PK? You need to specify your question, mainly what do you mean by 'difference'.

Comment: Yeah, right. (What a hell of a database?) CTEs are supported in all reasonable DBs including PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLite. Ill leave the answer here, maybe it will serve somebody else. It is by miles the most straigthforward and clean solution.

Comment: Windows functions will be supported in MySQL In the future version 8 if iam not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, it is supported since v8 (currently as public available preview version). However 'it' is not a window function but CTE.